# Remove Margin in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-relativelayout

I am using a RecyclerView in a Fragment. I want the fragment to match the parent in width and height. But this is my output.

[image: My output]

There is that space being left around the fragment. I want to eliminate that. I have tried everything, i.e, making the third parameter false, using parent container , changing the LayoutParams to match_parent but nothing has worked.

My code:-

Fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/RLGEVENT"
android:background="@color/white">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:src="@drawable/postbutton"
    android:id="@+id/floatingButton" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

     />
```

Fragment

```
  @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_gevent_main, container, false);

    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.RLGEVENT);
    rl.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    rl.invalidate();

    //code        

    return view;
}
```

Root.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout                         
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_start"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:insetForeground="@color/white"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Lolwa"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_start"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_start_drawer" />

   </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Row.xml

```
   <RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gEventRowRL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#fff">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/exampleProfilePic"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/background_profile_pic" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photoOf"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/gEventsDetails"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/black_total" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/geventTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/exampleProfilePic"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="18sp"

            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gEventsDetails"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/exampleProfilePic"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="16sp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gEventsDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/geventTitle"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/photoOf"
            android:text="" />


    </RelativeLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

app_bar_start.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
   tools:context="com.example.anubhavr.firebase.StartActivity">

   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

     <include layout="@layout/content_start" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Activity

```
   @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    com.example.anubhavr.firebase.Global_Events.MainActivity mainActivity = new com.example.anubhavr.firebase.Global_Events.MainActivity();
    setListener(mainActivity);

    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_home, mainActivity, mainActivity.getTag()).commit();


}
```

Comment: Post the root layout, that this fragment is being added to.

Comment: Also post the row of the recycler view

Comment: Post also `app_bar_start.xml`.

Comment: how will that help ??

Comment: Most possibly you are adding your `Fragment` on some `View` from `app_bar_start` layout.

Comment: Post your app_bar_start.xml

Comment: Can you please post your activity class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The padding should be in content_start

Comment: There is no padding applied in any resource file.Which padding are you talking about sir?

Comment: Inside app_bart_start you have <include layout="@layout/content_start" /> content_start is an xml layout, I can't see it in your question, maybe I miss it. But for what I see your fragment should be inside of that.